# Use labels with ggdag and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, directed-acyclic-graphs, ggdag

I'm using ggdag to create a DAG such as

```
test <- dagify("a" ~ "b",
    "b" ~ "c",
    "c" ~ "d",
    "b" ~ "d",
    exposure = "b",
    outcome = "d",
    labels = c(a = "A",
        b = "B",
        c = "D"))
```

And with ggplot I can get nice control of the colors such as

```
test %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
        geom_dag_point(color = "orange") +
        geom_dag_edges_arc(edge_color = "blue", curvature = 0) +
        geom_dag_text(color = "black") +
        theme_dag()
```

[image: pretty dag]

But I can't get it to display labels, such as in

```
ggdag(test, text = FALSE,
    use_labels = "label", edge_type = "link_arc")
```

[image: dag with labels]

How do I get labels with DAGs and ggplot?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for here. There _are_ labels in your final plot (the white boxes with the letters in them). What is it that you are expecting?

Comment: I'd like those labels to be in a ggplot figure, without having to use the `ggdag` convenience function, since it seems more stylistically limited than using the `ggplot` function with geoms

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the documentation refers to `geom_dag_repel_label` but the function is really `geom_dag_label_repel`

```
test %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
        geom_dag_point(color = "orange") +
        geom_dag_edges_arc(edge_color = "blue", curvature = 0) +
        geom_dag_label_repel(aes(label = label), colour = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
        theme_dag()
```

[image]